How to show line chart lines by year in SwiftUI?
I'm trying to group the rows by year, like in graph 1, but I'm not able to. I can only group them like in graph 2.
Graph 1:

Graph 2:
.
The sample code:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Sales {
    let id = UUID()
    let period: Date
    let value: Double
    
    init(value: Double, year: Int, month: Int) {
        self.value = value
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.year = year
        dateComponents.month = month
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        self.period = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    }
}

extension Sales {
    static var sampleData = [
        
        Sales(value: 300, year: 2020, month: 1),
        Sales(value: 230, year: 2020, month: 2),
        Sales(value: 190, year: 2020, month: 3),
        Sales(value: 250, year: 2020, month: 4),
        Sales(value: 270, year: 2020, month: 5),
        Sales(value: 280, year: 2020, month: 6),
        Sales(value: 290, year: 2020, month: 7),
        Sales(value: 400, year: 2020, month: 8),
        Sales(value: 300, year: 2020, month: 9),
        Sales(value: 360, year: 2020, month: 10),
        Sales(value: 400, year: 2020, month: 11),
        Sales(value: 450, year: 2020, month: 12),
        
        Sales(value: 320, year: 2021, month: 1),
        Sales(value: 280, year: 2021, month: 2),
        Sales(value: 300, year: 2021, month: 3),
        Sales(value: 390, year: 2021, month: 4),
        Sales(value: 400, year: 2021, month: 5),
        Sales(value: 450, year: 2021, month: 6),
        Sales(value: 420, year: 2021, month: 7),
        Sales(value: 500, year: 2021, month: 8),
        Sales(value: 550, year: 2021, month: 9),
        Sales(value: 490, year: 2021, month: 10),
        Sales(value: 600, year: 2021, month: 11),
        Sales(value: 650, year: 2021, month: 12),
        
        Sales(value: 400, year: 2022, month: 1),
        Sales(value: 330, year: 2022, month: 2),
        Sales(value: 430, year: 2022, month: 3),
        Sales(value: 450, year: 2022, month: 4),
        Sales(value: 600, year: 2022, month: 5),
        Sales(value: 650, year: 2022, month: 6),
        Sales(value: 550, year: 2022, month: 7),
        Sales(value: 580, year: 2022, month: 8),
        Sales(value: 600, year: 2022, month: 9),
        Sales(value: 650, year: 2022, month: 10),
        Sales(value: 600, year: 2022, month: 11),
        Sales(value: 800, year: 2022, month: 12)
    ]
}



struct TesteYearView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(Sales.sampleData, id: \.id) { datum in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Month", datum.period, unit: .month),
                    y: .value("Value", datum.value)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("year", datum.period, unit: .year))
                .symbol {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.pink)
                        .frame(width: 5)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .frame(height: 400)
        .padding()
        .chartYAxis(.hidden)
        
        Spacer()
    }
}

I'm trying to group using the command
.foregroundStyle(by: .value("year", datum.period, unit: .year))
but it's not working.
I don't know if the problem is using DateComponents or what it could be.
Please, if anyone can help me with this question I would be grateful (this is my first post on Stack Overflow, I hope I did it correctly).
Target IOS17

In some cases, converting dates to a string format seems to work better in Charts. Using Foundation's Date.formatted(), month and year can be converted to strings:
This changes the LineMark's x values from month to a string:
    x: .value("Month", datum.period.formatted(.dateTime.month(.abbreviated))),

and changes the foregroundStyle's year to a string:
    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("year", datum.period.formatted(.dateTime.year())))

The changes result in this:

The modified Chart code for reference:
    struct TesteYearView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Chart(Sales.sampleData, id: \.id) { datum in
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Month", datum.period.formatted(.dateTime.month(.abbreviated))),
                        y: .value("Value", datum.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("year", datum.period.formatted(.dateTime.year())))
                    .symbol {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.pink)
                            .frame(width: 5)
                    }
                }
                .chartLegend(position: .bottom, alignment: .leading, spacing: 5)
            }
            .frame(height: 400)
            .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }


Thanks a lot. I've tried to make "this answer is useful" but I don't have enough reputation to compute my vote.

If it answers your question, you can accept the answer. I placed the swiftui-charts tag so that it would get more visibility with Charts developers. So you could wait for more solutions if you prefer.
